# Find tty device file connected to stdin of any process on Linux

Tags: c, linux, tty, stat

I need to find the device file (`/dev/tty*` or `/dev/pts/*`) connected to the standard input of any process on my system. I want to implement something similar to the `tty(1)` program but which works for any process. How do I do this? This is on Linux.

The closest I've gotten is to parse the `/proc/pid/stat` file and read out the 6th column. This gives me a number that corresponds to the `st_rdev` of the `tty` file I'm interested in. I then have to run `stat(2)` on all the `/dev/tty*` and `/dev/pts/*` files to get the `st_rdev` numbers and use that to map back. This is the approach used in the [psutil](http://psutil.readthedocs.org/) package.

**Update:** I've taken a step back to reword this question into what I'm looking for rather than an implementation detail.

Comment: For the second part, note the device nodes may be dynamically created (udev, ...), and not exist yet. Tough I would expect most device nodes associated to terminals (except possibly USB-serial converters and the like) to always exist somewhere in `/dev`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, you may just do `ls -L /proc/pid/fd/0` to get the tty attached with the stdin of the process with process id `pid`.

Comment: That's what I've done now. I'll leave it like that for the time being. If something bites, I'll revisit this later.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) states:

> The st_dev field describes the device on which this file resides. (The major(3) and minor(3) macros may be useful to decompose the device ID in this field.)
>
> The st_rdev field describes the device that this file (inode) represents.

So the first one (`st_dev`) indicates on which device the actual *inode* you are inspecting resides, i.e. the disk that holds the `/dev` directory. This is typical meta information about the inode, like its size and so on.

The other (`st_rdev`) is used to map a driver to a device file, for e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something. That's basically the content of a device special file.

For the second question, I'm not sure off-hand. You would need to cross-index it with the list of mounted devices, and then recursively scan the proper one, I guess.

Comment: Hmmm. That's not something I'd considered. Let me take one more look at my application. I'll flesh out the question after that. Thanks.

Comment: I've reworded the question completely so this answer might look unrelated.